# Customizing exception in read-only property

Tags: python, exception, properties, customization

In a Python program I have a read-only property that I create using

```
bla = property(fget=_get_bla)
```

where _get_bla is a method defined in the class. When a program tries to write in this property

```
obj.bla = 1
```

I obviously get:

> AttributeError: can't set attribute

Is there a way to customize this exception? For example, I would like to change the message to

> 'bla' is a read-only property of class X

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add next method to your class:

```
def set_bla(self, value):
    raise AttributeError("'bla' is a read-only property of class X")
```

and

```
bla = property(fget=get_bla, fset=set_bla)
```

Comment: Of course! I was looking for a way to hack the property but this is much simpler.